# Indoor durian started do dry out

Tags: houseplants, pests, light, nutrients, dryness

I will really appreciate any help.
I grow a durian tree in my livingroom and so far it's been doing great. Since september, it started sheding leaves one by one (only one at a time always goes kind of "rusty" and then falls off long before actually appearing dead, it only changes color a little bit), and also young branches first sheded leaves and now are drying out from the top. I repeatedly searched for any kind of parasite (webs, residues, etc) but couldn't find any. Also, I thought it might not be getting enough light, so I bought some additional.

I include pictures of dried out branches, the whole tree and its stand and also the soil - there are some white spots, maybe it has something to do with it too..
[image: soil]

[image: the stand]

[image: dried out branches]

[image: dried out branches]